# Using Go installed by non-default golang package on Debian

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I am trying to install go 1.8.

The apt package of anything but golang-1.7 doesn't work. Golang-1.7 installs properly, golang-1.8 doesn't. Is the package in the repo wrong/incomplete?

Debian claims for golang-1.8
"This package is a metapackage that, when installed, guarantees that (most of) a full Go development environment is installed." https://packages.debian.org/stretch/golang-1.8
But that's obviously not true.

```
# apt install golang-1.8 golang-1.8-go
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
golang-1.8 is already the newest version (1.8.1-1).
golang-1.8-go is already the newest version (1.8.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
# go
bash: /usr/bin/go: No such file or directory
# whereis go
go:
# uname -a
Linux linux 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/debian_version 
9.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

«guarantees … is installed» merely means it *depends* on a set of packages which actually provide Go dev. env.

As you [can see](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/golang-1.8),
this package depends on three other packages—`golang-1.8-doc`,
`golang-1.8-go`, `golang-1.8-src`—so when you install `golang-1.8`,
those three will be installed as well.

The problem you're experiencing is, I must admit, indeed confusing
but can be easily explained.

If you'll look at [the list of packages installed by `golang-1.8-go`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/golang-1.8-go/filelist), you'll see that the `go` tool is installed as `/usr/lib/go-1.8/bin/go`,
and the directory `/usr/lib/go-1.8/bin` is not listed in the
default `PATH` environment variable (set by `/etc/profile`).

The reason it's done this way is twofold:

- There can be several groups of `golang-X.Y*` packages in the same
  Debian suite at the same time; say, Stretch has 1.7 and 1.8.

  It's crucial to understand that they are co-installable,
  which may be useful to test how a project which was tested
  against `X.Y` will work with `X.Y+N`.
- Debian provides a special "the most generic" Go package
  which depends on a specific `golang-X.Y` package which was deemed
  to be "the standard" for the parcicular Debian release.

  In Stretch, it's [`golang-go`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/golang-go),
  and as you can see, it has "1.7" in its version and depends on
  `golang-1.7-go`.

  This package makes sure the executable binaries
  provided by a specific default `golang-X.Y-go` package are available
  in "the standard place" — under `/usr/bin`
  ([see for yourself](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/golang-go/filelist)).

### What to do about it?

Several possiblilties:

- Merely call `/usr/lib/go-1.8/bin/go` by its full pathname.

  The `go` tool "knows" where its `GOROOT` is so it will find its
  packages specific to its version just fine.
- Prepend that directory to your path variable;
  say put something like

  ```
   export PATH="/usr/lib/go-1.8/bin:$PATH"
  ```

  into your `~/.bashrc` script
  and the next call to `go` will find it in the new place.
- Grab the source of the `golang-go` package, fix it so that it
  makes `golang-1.8-go` the default package, build it and install.

  (I'd not recommend to go this way just yet.)

Hope this helps.

---

#### Another stab at explaining

Stretch has two packs of three packages: `golang-1.7-*` and `golang-1.8-*`.

In each, pack, the `golang-1.N-go` package installs its `go` binary under `/usr/lib/go-1.N/bin`. *Neither of them installs a symlink* under `/usr/bin`.

The reason for this is to make these packs of packages *co-installable,*
so that you can compile your Go code with any of the installed versions.

Now there is *another,* independent, package, which does not encode Go release version in its name.
It's named `golang-go`, and it depends only on `golang-1.7-go`
where `1.7` is the *default* version of Go runtime for Stretch.

In another release, `golang-go` will depend on another `golang-X.Y-go`
package.

It is *this* package, which provides `/usr/bin/go` pointing at
`/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/go`.

So if (and only if) you have `golang-go` installed, will you have
the `go` binary available under `/usr/bin`, and that will be of Go
1.7 in Stretch.

And no, it's not possible to somehow force `golang-go` to point at
`go` from the installed `golang-1.8-go` package, and neither is there
a way to select a preferred Go version via the "dpkg alternatives"
mechanism.

My take on "the why" of this approach is to have a well-known version
of `go` in any given Debian release. This is supposedly needed for
building Debian packages of software written in Go.
Otherwise, it would be required for package building machinery to invent
some trickery for finding the default version of Go;
as of now, their source packages may
just depend on `golang-go` and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know now how to access the program but I still am confused about why this happens, I never had this. Yes golang-1.8 installs all the deps you mentioned but shouldn't then be at least a symlink created with /usr/bin/go -> /usr/lib/go-1.8/bin/go?

Comment: I've explained this. Supposedly I failed to convery that properly. Let's have another stab. Updated my answer.